# How to set xtics automatically to x values in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

In a simple diagram:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot table [x=P, y=Tp, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

that uses the data set `data.csv`:

```
P,Tp,Lin
4.0,896.13,896.13
8.0,778.26,448.065
16.0,657.84,224.0325
32.0,460.04,112.01625
64.0,302.5,56.008125
```

how can I *use the column values of the x-axis (P) to set the xtick labels* of the diagram that now looks like this:

[image]

Comment: `\begin{axis}[xtick=data]`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: thanks, this is it, I found it now in the manual as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.